# SSAS Realtime Processing

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I created a cube in SSAS, how I can extract real time data from the data source to my cube?

I mean if any data modification (insert, update, delete) happens, SSAS should update the cube.

Answer (score 5):

You need to look into proactive caching for your [partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-olap-logical-cube-objects/partitions-proactive-caching) and [dimensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models-olap-logical-dimension-objects/proactive-caching-dimensions) where you can set up notifications based on a tracking table.

From the documentation:

> Proactive caching provides automatic MOLAP cache creation and
>   management for OLAP objects. The cubes immediately incorporate changes
>   that are made to the data in the database, based upon notifications
>   received from the database. The goal of proactive caching is to
>   provide the performance of traditional MOLAP, while retaining the
>   immediacy and ease of management offered by ROLAP.

The subject is a bit broad for an answer and there are quite a few options and drawbacks to consider.

In general you check the box "enable proactive caching" and pick some latency options:

[image]

and then you specify a tracking table on the "notification" tab:

[image]

What all the options such as enable ROLAP aggregations and the latency settings do is explained in more detail [in this blog post](http://bidn.com/Blogs/near-real-time-olap-using-ssas-proactive-caching) or [this one](https://jeffprom.com/2012/11/27/proactive-caching-in-ssas/)